# Post Request - Spring boot [RequestBody] vs Asp.net [FromBody]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asp.net-web-api

I just encounter a problem in spring boot post request. I have an API endpoint which is taking the `String` parameter as below:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/products/add")
public RestMessage addProduct(@RequestBody String name) {
   //Code implementation here   
}
```

When I am testing this API endpoint from the postman, the name parameter is population as **`name = "\"value\""`**;

My postman request is as:

[image: Postman Request]

I'm recently migrated from .net and if I compare it with the Web API 2 method I would have an implementation as

```
[Route("products/add")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]string name)
{
    //Code implementation here
}
```

And if I test this endpoint from the postman then I would have name parameter value a simple string as **`name = "value"`**.

What to do to achieve the exact same behavior in Spring Boot. What I understand is Spring Boot is considering the inverted commas as a string rather than a json part.

If I am sending the request in this format
[image]

This is the result
[image: This is what happening]

**Updated**: So after a few testing I found out the behavior that ASP.net considers the postman string value as a string object, it neglects the inverted commas for you. But in Spring boot if you have a single parameter as a string and you have to pass it in the @RequestBody then don't stringify it. The sample request which works for me as:

[image: Working request]

So don't need to bother about the cross sign in the postman.

Comment: RequestBody is used to map json to an object, for single value uou can use RequestParam, may be you can try sending only value in post body since it is single value

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a POJO.

```
Class NameDTO {
    private String name;
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
       return this.name;
    }
}
```

@RequestBody NameDTO nameDTO

Now you can get name using

```
name = nameDTO.getName
```

Comment: No, it has stringify the whole object as "\"name\":\"value\""

Comment: What is the content-type? If content-type is application-json then it should take only value. Also did you use the curly braces?